# The configured maxUrlLength value is not being used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I received the error "The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.".  So I went into my Web.Config file, under `configuration` - `system.web`
.  I added an attribute on the `httpRuntime` section as follows:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxUrlLength="1083" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

I still get the error.  I've rebuilt, republished, stopped and started IIS, everything I can think of.  The URL I am using has roughly 600 characters in it.  What else can I do here?

Comment: on which browser(-s) and which version do you receive this error?

Comment: Have you tried setting it for the server's .config file instead of at the website level?

Comment: @bejger I tested Chrome 33 and IE 11.

Comment: @Josh - I have not. I was under the impression this handled it.  Also I'm very unfamiliar with IIS. I'll look for that now.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all.  I am trying to use an OAuth returned URL.  I just found that it's in the form of http://www.foo.com/&foo=bar?foo2=bar2.  The ampersand and the question mark are reversed.  Looks like I'm getting a bad URL back from Intuit.  I simply didn't notice that because the URL was so long.  (I also think the error message from IIS is wrong).  I will investigate more.

Answer (score -1):

The configuration change for maxUrlLength needs to be made in the root Web.config for the .NET Framework. This file is located in %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\framework_version\CONFIG